# php and html with arrays, if and else

Tags: php, html, if-statement, while-loop

I was trying to make data from an array either go left (DR) or right (CR) when meeting certain conditions. My problem is with display, on the logic and the display.

```
// While Looping - Its fine here!
while ($newArray_pin = mysql_fetch_array($result_pin)) {
    // Here is fine also
    $amount = $newArray_pin['net_reduction'];
    $dr_cr_action = $newArray_pin['dr_cr_code_inc'];

    //I don't know what am doing wrong here, problem starts here
    if ($dr_cr_action === 'DR') { 
    $show_dr_amount = $amount;
    } else { 
    $show_cr_amount = $amount;
    }

    $display_block_pin .= "<tr>
        <td><div class=\"text-center\">$joint_account_numbers</div></td>
        <td><div class=\"text-left\">$account_title</div></td>
        <td><div class=\"text-right\">$show_dr_amount</div></td>
        <td><div class=\"text-right\">$show_cr_amount</div></td>
        </tr>";
    }

    $display_block_pin .= "</table>";
    print $display_block_pin;
```

// On table display, records does not go left and right as I expected with the variable $show_dr_amount and $show_cr_amount

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear but..Firstly, inside the two `<div>`'s you have both `text-right` (it is the same for `$show_dr_amount` and `$show_cr_amount`). Secondly, have you tried to `print_r()` those variables to be sure that they hold the desirable data?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos yes, I just tried the `print_r()`, its outputting the desired result. I want the data from `$dr_cr_action` which holds either `DR` or `CR`. Based on this condition, if its `true`, I want it to show `$amount` here `$show_dr_amount` **else** `$show_cr_amount`

Comment: It got me confused because `$display_block_pin` has both of these variables(`$show_dr_amount` and `$show_cr_amount`). Shouldn't it be only one?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos yes, it should actually. I think, you just made me realize the error. Thanks, I guess I can take it from here. **Am grateful**